# Can headers and response text be accessed from the forge.request.ajax error callback?

Tags: trigger.io, digest-authentication

I'm trying to set up a trigger.io project that uses HTTP Digest Authentication. So far I've only been testing things in the Android emulator.

I have a stand-alone JavaScript version that uses jQuery that I'm using as a base. In the jQuery version Digest Authentication is triggered by sending a "401 Not Authorized" header along with the nonce, etc. in a custom "WWW-Authenticate-JS" header. Using a custom header instead of "WWW-Authenticate" prevents the browser from triggering it's own authentication form. The error callback in forge.request.ajax, however, does not seem to have access to this data. When I output the response none of the data sent by the server is there, except for the fact that the header was a 401.

Is it possible to get access to the returned headers and body from the error callback? If so, what do I need to do to access this data?

I have also tried using the standard Digest Authentication header for the trigger.io calls, but that leads to NULL pointer errors in io.trigger.forge.android.modules.request.API, specifically in the getPasswordAuthentication method. Can forge.request.ajax be configured to automatically use Digest Authentication when the standard header is returned?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this adapter that I wrote https://gist.github.com/3846989

Comment: After a bit more work, I found that when I return a 403 instead of a 401 I can at least access the response content. Which allows me to pass the Digest Authentication headers in the body. Not ideal, but it is a work-around.

Comment: Check out my [example app](http://github.com/burgalon/boorgle-spine) which uses basic auth for logging-in an existing user and retrieving an oauth token ([line](https://github.com/burgalon/boorgle-spine/blob/master/app/controllers/user_edit.coffee#L48)). No hacks used.